# Java grouping coordinates based on an array of positions

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of x that contains some double arrays as below:

```
 double x[] = {2, 4, 1, 1};
```

I also have 3 arrays that defines the position of the x value in each group:

```
 int[] cluster1 = {1}; //which means that first value in x array belongs to cluster 1
 int[] cluster2 = {2}; //second value in x array belongs to cluster 2
 int[] cluster3 = {3, 4}; //third value & forth value in x array belongs to cluster 3.
```

How do obain the output such as below?

```
Cluster 1: (2)
Cluster 2: (4)
Cluster 3: (1), (1)
```

It is also worth noting that sometimes the same value may appear two times in different cluster. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand your question. Could you please try to re-phrase it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't really see any effort just a code writing request

Comment: It seems like your `cluster` arrays are basically indices for the `x[]` and `y[]` arrays, which begs the question how come they're `Double` and not `Integer`? Unless I missed something...

Comment: Write down on a piece of paper, **using words**, how you would solve this problem.  Keep breaking the problem down into smaller and smaller problems until you can write code for each small problem.

Comment: @OriLentz tis is small part of the code. The cluster could be in integer type. I've changed it to integer

Comment: @Cael OK, but given the small part of code you supplied, I'm not wrong, am I? All you basically want is to do `x[index]` and `y[index]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    /* Values Array */
    double x[] = {2, 4, 1, 1};
    double y[] = {1, 3, 1, 9};

    /* Clusters Array */
    Double[] cluster1 = {1.0};
    Double[] cluster2 = {2.0};
    Double[] cluster3 = {3.0, 4.0};

    /* Print Cluster 1 Values */
    System.out.print("Cluster 1:");
    for(int i = 0; i < cluster1.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" (" + x[cluster1[i].intValue() - 1] + "," + y[cluster1[i].intValue() - 1] + ")");
    }

    /* Print Cluster 2 Values */
    System.out.print("\nCluster 2:");
    for(int i = 0; i < cluster2.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" (" + x[cluster2[i].intValue() - 1] + "," + y[cluster2[i].intValue() - 1] + ")");
    }

    /* Print Cluster 3 Values */
    System.out.print("\nCluster 3:");
    for(int i = 0; i < cluster3.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" (" + x[cluster3[i].intValue() - 1] + "," + y[cluster3[i].intValue() - 1] + ")");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Cluster 1: (2.0,1.0)
Cluster 2: (4.0,3.0)
Cluster 3: (1.0,1.0) (1.0,9.0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going to make it easier to understand but this achieves the output

Comment: @Cael Your Welcome! Would appreciate if you accept the answer.